# What is the difference between QGLWidget and QOpenGLWidget?

Tags: qt

I was reading through some examples on the net to use Qt for rendering stuff with OpenGL and most of then use QGLWidget. However, when I was using Qt Designer I noticed it adds a QOpenGLWidget to the form.

What pros/cons have one over the other?

Comment: The QGL* classes are pretty much obsolete and currently only kept around to keep old source code working while the QOpenGL* classes are their replacement, so you should use the latter in pretty much any case.

The documentation for the OpenGL module also states this as a warning: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most important point is that QGLWidget only exists for compatibility reasons to older codebases. As suggested in the Qt documentation on [QGLWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html), starting from Qt 5.4 you should use QOpenGLWidget instead.

Generally, the new [QOpenGLWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html)

> retains the familiar initializeGL/resizeGL/paintGL API, while enabling full interoperability with other widgets in complex user interfaces.

as detailed in [this blog post](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/09/10/qt-weekly-19-qopenglwidget/). This includes:

- Offscreen rendering using framebuffer objects instead of a native window. This has performance advantages on mobile platforms.
- Enhanced support for instantiating explicit OpenGL profiles
- Context sharing between widgets has been simplified
- There are subtle differences in the setup of the OpenGL state
- Direct support for multisampling

In short: If you have the choice, always go for QOpenGLWidget as there is virtually no downside if you do not have to maintain backwards compatibility.